# App stops after calling performSegue inside Touch ID block

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue, touch-id

Hi I’m experiencing a strange behavior I really don’t understand.

I present a touch ID identification to the user and if he’s authorized I 
call a [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"callCustomSegue" sender:self];
inside the block in this way:

```
[myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
                  localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
                            reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                                if (success) {
                                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"callCustomSegue" sender:self];
```

Then the app stops for several seconds (at least 3-4) then next ViewController is presented.

The perform called by “callCustomSegue” does this:

```
- (void) perform {

    src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    dst = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    [src.view addSubview:dst.view];

}
```

I don’t understand what’s happening between the identification on touch ID and the performSegueWithIdentifier
and why the app stops.

If I bypass the touch ID and just call the performSegueWithIdentifier works immediately as I would expect.

If I put in the touch ID block:

```
[myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
                  localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
                            reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                                if (success) {
                    authenticated = YES;
                        [self showMessage:@"Authentication is successful" withTitle:@"Success"];
                }
```

where showMessage does this:

```
 UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                  message:message
                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


    UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                             actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                             {
                                 [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                 if (authenticated) {
                                     [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"callCustomSegue" sender:self];
                                 }

                                 if (!authenticated) {
                                     [self touchID];
                                 }

                             }];
```

after tapping OK the next ViewController is called immediately.

So the question is: why I can’t call performSegue within the touch ID block and get an immediate response?

Any idea where I’m wrong?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform all UI related activities on the main queue.  The `reply` block for the touchID process is not guaranteed to be executing on the main queue.  In fact you can almost guarantee that it won't be.

You should have -

```
  if (success) {
     authenticated = YES;
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"callCustomSegue" sender:self];
     });
```

Comment: Thanx so much, I just learned something new to me. Thank you again, works flawlessly.